# MS SQL - subquery to check if value exists in group by

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to build such a query ?

Table **one** has 10 values, table **two** has 100 values.

Table **one**:

```
id   | name   | value | weekStart  | weekEnd     | superValue
-----+--------+-------+------------+-------------+-----------
1    | tom    |  1    | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-07  |    A
2    | tom    |  1    | 2016-08-01 | 2016-01-14  |    E
3    | mark   |  0    | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-07  |    A
```

Table **two**:

```
id   | name   | age
-----+--------+----
1    | tom    | 16
2    | Xavier | 19
3    | mark   | 20
4    | bob    | 20
5    | alan   | 35
```

I have joined them (one record to many) based on their name, and then grouped them by name.

So that we have a resault something like this :

```
id   | name   | value | (min)weekStart | (max)weekEnd 
-----+--------+-------+----------------+-------------
1    | tom    |  1    | 2016-01-01     | 2016-01-14
2    | mark   |  0    | 2016-01-01     | 2016-01-07
```

Is there a way to display an additional column with the value based on the first tables column (superValue) if any of the values for this name has value 'E' then 'Yes' else 'No'

```
id   | name   | value | (min)weekStart | (max)weekEnd | is it super ?
-----+--------+-------+----------------+--------------+---------------
1    | tom    |  1    | 2016-01-01     | 2016-01-14   |   Yes
2    | mark   |  0    | 2016-01-01     | 2016-01-07   |   No
```

Comment: `MySQL` as your tag says, or `SQL Server` as your title says ?? Which is it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get, how you handled one.value, but this is my solution:
(so you actually don't need a subquery for this.)

```
select
    `two`.`id`,
    `two`.`name`,
    max(`one`.`value`) as `value`,
    min(`one`.`weekStart`) as `minWeekStart`,
    max(`one`.`weekEnd`) as `maxWeekEnd`,
    sum(if(`one`.`superValue` = 'E', 1, 0)) > 0 as `is it super?`
from
    `two`
    inner join `one`
        on (`two`.`name` = `one`.`name`)
group by
    `two`.`name`
order by
    `two`.`id`;
```

It would be nicer if you reference table `two` by the id, and not by the name.

EDIT: A little explanation how it works:

```
sum(if(`one`.`superValue` = 'E', 1, 0)) > 0 as `is it super?`
```

The "if" statement inside the sum returns 1 is the value is 'E' and returns 0 otherwise. The sum just adds these 0's and 1's together, and at the end we check if the sum is larger than 0, meaning: Was there at least one 'E' value.

Comment: seems ok, but what if the 'super Values' is int ... sum would then add the value of them.

Comment: It wouldn't because the "sum" contains an "if" statement. The results of the "if" statements are summed up. So you would change it to: sum(if(`one`.`superValue` = 666, 1, 0)) > 0 and so on. Wait I'll add an explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Just add another column to your `select` using `case`. Replace table-one with alias of table-one if given in inner join or actual name of table one.

```
select <existing-columns>,Case when Max(table-one.superValue) = 'E' then 'yes' else 'no' end as [is-it-super]
from <existing-joins>
```

Comment: looks like this could also solve me issue, but what if i had int as a 'supervalue'. Min would only compare the lowest value.

Comment: If 'supervalue' is an int then you can map the maximum value of column 'supervalue' to 'E'